# Additional namespace prefix during JAXB marshalling

Tags: xml, namespaces, jaxb, marshalling

I have got problem with JAXB marshalling in Java 1.6_u33

I`ve got 5 schemas .xsd which are used for generating Java classes and then marshalling XML file.

Problem is with only one case - for this file JAXB generate additional namespace prefix ns2. This is very strange because all schemas are identical and marshalling mechnism is generic for all of them.

Generation mechanism:

```
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
            Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.marshal(file, doc);
```

And the first lines of bad xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ns2:Document xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.056.001.01">
  <ns2:camt.056.001.01>
    <ns2:Assgnmt>
      <ns2:Id>NOTPROVIDED</ns2:Id>
      <ns2:CreDtTm>2008-06-24T00:00:00</ns2:CreDtTm>
    </ns2:Assgnmt>
```

With the same settings xml generated from another xsd is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.029.001.03">
  <camt.029.001.03>
    <Assgnmt>
      <Id>NOTPROVIDED</Id>
      <CreDtTm>2008-03-26T00:00:00</CreDtTm>
    </Assgnmt>
```

I would be very grateful for any help... Thanks.

---

I couldn`t add answer to my question so I add here my explanation.

For not properly working package:

Package-info:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.056.001.01", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package eu.axabank.axaconverter.datamodel.camt056;
```

Object-factory

```
package eu.axabank.axaconverter.datamodel.camt056;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the eu.axabank.axaconverter.datamodel.camt056 package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: eu.axabank.axaconverter.datamodel.camt056
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link CaseAssignmentBIC }
     * 
     */
    public CaseAssignmentBIC createCaseAssignmentBIC() {
        return new CaseAssignmentBIC();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link UnderlyingTransaction }
     * 
     */
    public UnderlyingTransaction createUnderlyingTransaction() {
        return new UnderlyingTransaction();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link PaymentTransactionInformation }
     * 
     */
    public PaymentTransactionInformation createPaymentTransactionInformation() {
        return new PaymentTransactionInformation();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link RemittanceInformation }
     * 
     */
    public RemittanceInformation createRemittanceInformation() {
        return new RemittanceInformation();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link OriginalTransactionReference }
     * 
     */
    public OriginalTransactionReference createOriginalTransactionReference() {
        return new OriginalTransactionReference();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ControlData }
     * 
     */
    public ControlData createControlData() {
        return new ControlData();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Document }
     * 
     */
    public Document createDocument() {
        return new Document();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link CancellationReasonInformationBICorName }
     * 
     */
    public CancellationReasonInformationBICorName createCancellationReasonInformationBICorName() {
        return new CancellationReasonInformationBICorName();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ActiveOrHistoricCurrencyAndAmountEUR }
     * 
     */
    public ActiveOrHistoricCurrencyAndAmountEUR createActiveOrHistoricCurrencyAndAmountEUR() {
        return new ActiveOrHistoricCurrencyAndAmountEUR();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Camt056 }
     * 
     */
    public Camt056 createCamt056() {
        return new Camt056();
    }

}
```

For good working package:

package-info:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.029.001.03", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package eu.axabank.axaconverter.datamodel.camt029;
```

And object factory looks exactly the same (except naming of course).

I have tried QName element - it is inconvenient due the generic nature of mechanizm - but withount any good result.

I was using NamespacePrefixMapper:

```
        NamespacePrefixMapper mapper = new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
            public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri,
                    String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
                return "";
            }
        };
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper",
                mapper);
```

but this mapper did`t work! He was setting - but method getPreferredPrefix was never called during mershalling.

I don`t understand different beetwen my 4 schemas and this not working one...

Comment: What is in the package-info / objectfactory? It got something to do with the default namespace.

Comment: Replay for you Alexander added to the end of original post.

Comment: urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.056.001.01.xsd, what are the namespaces/targetnamespace here? can you provide a sample project?

Comment: namespace is my own name constructed according to Universal financial industry message scheme ISO 200022. Does it matter?

Comment: Ok I was wrong. The xsd is not important here. I got no clue when looking at the code examples.

Comment: Yes, it is really weird. All works properly for 4 case but not in this one... The most interesting is that about 2 weeks ago everything was working good. I don`t know why and what is the reason but it just has stoped working... Maybe some change in maven-jaxb2-plugin is responsible for that? I don`t think because I was trying 3 versions of this plugin... Here is something with marshalling...But what? I have no idea... Anyway thank you for responses Alexander;)

Comment: Well I dont use the maven-jaxb2-plugin. For my project I generated the jaxb objects directly with xjc with annotations.

Comment: Funny... I have generate classes using clear XJC right now and this is the same result. I am pritty sure that this problem in connected to Marshaller and not to JAXB classes or package-info..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem detected!

I am confused but it was my mistake.

To get down to brass tacks:

I generated 5 packages of Java classes from 5 different schemas. They were importing however one schema with simple types (common objects for schemas). I this common XSD I placed mainly  objects....yeah mainly. There were 2  elements...unfortunately. This complexTypes were used only by object generated in this one - not working - case.

The point is that 2 objects was generating from another Objectfactory - placed in another package!

I deduce that mixing objects from more than one Object factory in one marshalling object couse problem descrbed in my first post.

Clue is: **If you dont want have many namespaces in XML u should never use two Object factories or import schemas with complex type.**